# OpenCL - Approximation of Pi via Monte Carlo Simulation - Bad Values

Tags: c, parallel-processing, opencl, pi, approximation

I am currently developing a Monte Carlo simulation that should approximate Pi. I do the parallelization via OpenCL, but I get significantly worse time values via OpenCL than not parallelized. What am I doing wrong? I have a MacBookPro with an Intel Iris, Intel CPU and AMD graphics card.

The implementation has to happen with OpenCL not with other standards.

Thanks in advance.

My Main Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
 
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif
 
#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)
 
int main(void) {

    // ------- 

    // -------
    struct timeval start;
    struct timeval stop;
    //struct timeval differenz;
    // Create the two input vectors
    unsigned long i, j;
    unsigned long inner = 0;
    unsigned long outer = 0;
    const unsigned long LIST_SIZE = pow(2,16);
    const unsigned long LAUF_VAR = 1;
    unsigned long *A = (unsigned long*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long)*LIST_SIZE);
    unsigned long *C = (unsigned long*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long)*LIST_SIZE);
    unsigned long *B = (unsigned long*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long)*LIST_SIZE);
 
    // Load the kernel source code into the array source_str
    FILE *fp;
    char *source_str;
    size_t source_size;
 
    fp = fopen("square.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread( source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose( fp );
 
    // Get platform and device information
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;   
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1, 
            &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
 
    // Create an OpenCL context
    cl_context context = clCreateContext( NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);
 
 
    // Create memory buffers on the device for each vector 
    cl_mem a_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, 
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(unsigned long), NULL, &ret);
    cl_mem b_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, LIST_SIZE * sizeof(unsigned long), NULL, &ret);
    cl_mem c_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, 
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(unsigned long), NULL, &ret);
 
    // Create a program from the kernel source
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, 
            (const char **)&source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);
 
    // Build the program
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS)
    {                 
        printf("Error: Failed to build program executable!\n");
        perror("");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Create a command queue
    cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);
 
    // Create the OpenCL kernel
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "square_val", &ret);
 
    // Set the arguments of the kernel
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&a_mem_obj);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&b_mem_obj);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&c_mem_obj);

    // Execute the OpenCL kernel on the list
    size_t global_item_size = LIST_SIZE; // Process the entire lists
    size_t local_item_size = 64; // Divide work items into groups of 64
 
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    // Display the result to the screen
    /*
    for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%ld^2 + %ld^2 = %ld\n", A[i], B[i], C[i]);
    }
    */
    for(j = 0; j < LAUF_VAR; j++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));

        for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
            A[i] = (unsigned long) rand() % LIST_SIZE;   
            B[i] = (unsigned long) rand() % LIST_SIZE;
        }

        // Copy the lists A and B to their respective memory buffers
        ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, a_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
                LIST_SIZE * sizeof(unsigned long), A, 0, NULL, NULL);
        ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, b_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0, LIST_SIZE * sizeof(unsigned long), B, 0, NULL, NULL);
        

        ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, 
            &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
 
        // Read the memory buffer C on the device to the local variable C
        ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, c_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0, LIST_SIZE * sizeof(unsigned long), C, 0, NULL, NULL);

        for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++)
        {
            if(C[i] <= (LIST_SIZE * LIST_SIZE))
            {
                inner++;
            } else {
                outer++;
            }
        }
    }
    gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);


    printf("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n");
    printf("Parallel\n");
    printf("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n");
    printf("Inner as unsigned long: %ld\n", inner);
    printf("Outer as unsigned long: %ld\n", outer);
    printf("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n");
    double innerDouble = (double) (inner);
    double outerDouble = (double) (outer);
    double val = (innerDouble/LIST_SIZE);
    printf("Approximation for PI: %.20lf\n", (val*4) / LAUF_VAR);
    printf("@Walk NR: %ld\n", j);
    printf("LIST_SIZE: %lu\n", LIST_SIZE);
    printf("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n");
    printf("took %lu us\n", (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000 + stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec); 
    //printf("%ju\n",(uintmax_t)SIZE_MAX);

    // Clean up
    ret = clFlush(command_queue);
    ret = clFinish(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(a_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(b_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(c_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseContext(context);
    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);

    // Create the two input vectors
    inner = 0;
    outer = 0;
    unsigned long *D = (unsigned long*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long)*LIST_SIZE);
    unsigned long *E = (unsigned long*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long)*LIST_SIZE);
    unsigned long *F = (unsigned long*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long)*LIST_SIZE);

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    for(j = 0; j < LAUF_VAR; j++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));

        for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
            D[i] = (unsigned long) rand() % LIST_SIZE;   
            E[i] = (unsigned long) rand() % LIST_SIZE;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
            F[i] = D[i] * D[i] + E[i] * E[i];
            if(F[i] <= (LIST_SIZE * LIST_SIZE))
            {
                inner++;
            } else {
                outer++;
            }
        }
    }
    gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);

    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");


    printf("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n");
    printf("Seriell\n");
    printf("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n");
    printf("Inner as unsigned long: %ld\n", inner);
    printf("Outer as unsigned long: %ld\n", outer);
    printf("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n");
    innerDouble = (double) (inner);
    outerDouble = (double) (outer);
    val = (innerDouble/LIST_SIZE);
    printf("Approximation for PI: %.20lf\n", (val*4) / LAUF_VAR);
    printf("@Walk NR: %ld\n", j);
    printf("LIST_SIZE: %lu\n", LIST_SIZE);
    printf("took %lu us\n", (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000 + stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec); 

    free(D);
    free(E);
    free(F);

    return 0;
}
```

the Kernel:

```
__kernel void square_val(__global const unsigned long *A, __global const unsigned long *B, __global unsigned long *C) {
 
    // Get the index of the current element to be processed
    unsigned long i = get_global_id(0);
 
    // Do the operation
    C[i] = A[i] * A[i] + B[i] * B[i];
}
```

the Results:

```
 ./test                                                                                                                                                   
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Parallel
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Inner as unsigned long: 51383
Outer as unsigned long: 14153
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Approximation for PI: 3.13616943359375000000
@Walk NR: 1
LIST_SIZE: 65536
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
took 3678 us



- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Seriell
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Inner as unsigned long: 51383
Outer as unsigned long: 14153
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Approximation for PI: 3.13616943359375000000
@Walk NR: 1
LIST_SIZE: 65536
took 2010 us
```

Comment: OT (maybe): You should move `srand(time(NULL));` outside of the loops, the seeding is usually needed only once, unless you want to reset the generator with a specific seed to always obtain the same sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly the kernel is too short both in global size and work per workitem. I.e. offload time is dominating actual computation. A global size of 64k workitems is tiny for simple kernels even on integrated graphics. Secondly, the kernel is doing very little work per workitem: 2 muls + 1 add. Think of sending a simple math problem to a really wide calculator on Mars and waiting for the answer. We want to do more work per work item.

For example, older Intel HD (Skylake or earlier) loads take around 100-150c (100 to 150 nanoseconds) if you hit L3 and much more even on misses. And this holds even if you use a zero-copy buffer (which you still should if you can). I didn't scrutinize the host code very much, but I am think this is streaming access (different memory for each workitem), so caching won't be very good. Finally, for the given kernel on the Intel part above the thread dispatcher won't be able to fully occupy the compute units. That is, threads will exit/finish faster than new ones can be loaded ("thread dispatch limited").

I can't speak for the other part you listed. However, I would worry about shipping so much data across to a discrete part for so little work (and then sending it back). Almost certainly it won't be as good as the CPU.

Here are three ideas.

1. Move the random variable work onto the GPU. Find a good simple linear (or permuted) congruential random number generator (RNG) that is GPU friendly. You'll have to seed it independently per work item and it's best if you can get a few random variables out of it rather than just one. I am not an on RNG splitting, but possibly `(uint)get_global_id(0)` is a sufficient seed for something like XORWOW or PCG. Stay away from the Mersenne Twister on the GPU (too much state).
2. Reduce the results on the GPU first and then on the host.  Monte Carlo (MC) pi approximations on the GPU usually distribute the final reduction onto the GPU.  That is, have a workgroup compute its own copy of `inner` and `outer` and then sum them all on the host or atomically per workgroup.  That is a workgroup of say 256 work items reduces its answers down one `inner` and one `outer`.  Then either atomic add that single value to a global copy or else to separate memory and let the host sum the workgroup sums. I am not sure which is better.
3. Batch the work. Have a work item compute K elements so that the RNG and reduction work is amortized away.

A hat tip to pmdj as well. He gives some very good advice on things to try as well, and I affirm most of his sentiments.

Fun Stuff!

Comment: Due to the use of 64-bit types, there are probably actually 6-24 muls and 6-12 add/sub operations happening. (depending on exactly how the 64-bit ops are decomposed into 32-bit ones on the platform - GPUs tend to be fast for 24-bit multiplications; I'm not sure if 64-bit muls get decomposed into 3 (slow) 32-bit muls, not counting the high word result computation, or if they get decomposed into even more 24-bit multiplications) Minor inaccuracy, the advice as such is good.

Comment: Correct. I ignored the compiler overhead: get_global_id()/buffer arithmetic and setup and showdown instructions because we're still not even close to covering dispatch and end-of-thread latency. (Again, I can't speak for the discrete part's guts, but likely there'd be a similar problem.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm hesitant to make blanket statements about what's fast or what's slow in your code without fine-grained profiling data, but here are some candidates for how to improve things:

- You are splitting the algorithm rather awkwardly across CPU and GPU, and are doing the maximum amount of memory copying, which presumably the pure CPU version doesn't do. Do as much *computation* on the GPU as possible, copy as little data as possible between device and host.
- Your values for `A` & `B` elements are in the range 0..65535. There is no need to make every element a 64-bit integer.
- Especially if you are using the Iris GPU which uses shared memory, use zero-copy buffers. There are detailed explanations of this, but essentially:

  - Don't: allocate host memory, fill it, then create a CL buffer and copy to that.
  - Instead: create a CL buffer, map it into host memory space, fill it directly through the mapped pointer, then unmap it.
- Generating the random numbers on GPU would save you a lot of memory bandwidth - no need to copy A & B to device memory. Not all random number generators are suitable for this though, and there certainly isn't one built into OpenCL.
- This: `if(C[i] <= (LIST_SIZE * LIST_SIZE))` is needlessly doing computation on the host. Yes, comparison is computation. If you perform this check in your kernel, you don't need to write to array C - or at least, you can write a 0 or 1 to an array of bytes instead of 64-bit integers. This will save you memory bandwidth and host side execution time.
- If you implement the above advice, you'll realise it would be best to just increment the inner/outer counters on GPU.

  1. You don't need 2 counters, the second one can be inferred by subtracting the first from the total iterations.
  2. The naive correct approach in OpenCL would be to use an atomic increment in every work-item.
  3. Atomically updating a single memory location from every work item won't perform great. Better: use work-groups. Work out by how much to increase the counter for all the elements a group using local memory, then perform an atomic addition to the global counter in just one of the group's work items.
- You may want to try processing more than one A/B pair per work-item after the above changes to further reduce overhead for accumulating the counts.

Comment: The 64-bit integer was also my first guess. Most GPUs are very bad at 64-bit data types. 32-bit (`uint`) should be much faster. Plus, there is some latency for PCIe copy and a `LIST_SIZE` of only 65k will probably not saturate the GPU enough to be efficient.

Comment: @ProjectPhysX For this problem size and memory behaviour, it'd definitely be interesting to see how the few-cores, shared memory GPU vs many-cores, discrete memory compare in performance.